# Android clear text

Tags: java, android

I'm putting text on screen with

```
text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"binary message sent: "+ msg + "\n");
```

How can I remove the text from the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text.setText("");   //that's all
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the TextView to display an empty text:

```
text.setText("");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the text to a blank field, use:

```
text.setText("");
```

If you want to hide the whole textView use:

```
text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```